# mod_rewrite to string special characters and shorten URL simultaneously

Tags: mod-rewrite, mediawiki

Gang,

Long time sysadmin but first time poster to this excellent site, so, please be gentle.

I am not strong at REGEX yet and trying to do two things at once on our internally hosted "mediawiki" site.

We are running an otherwise pretty plain jane LAMP stack (centOS 5.x, Apache 2.x, PHP 5.x). We are root. We are using /etc/httpd/conf.d/wiki.conf and not using .htaccess.  The physical path is /var/www/html/wiki/

I have partially successful results with some combination of the below, but I am not good enough to get it all the way there. I know that there are some mod_write studs on this site that I am hoping to avail.

1. I am following this recipe https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache so as to shorten URL's from www.example.com/wiki/index.php?=title=Garden_Store to www.example.com/wiki/Garden_Store
2. still allow the use of www.example.com/wiki/index.php?=title=Garden_Store should the user should choose to type out that syntax of URL. (I believe that is possible with mediawiki to use both style URL's at the same time. If it is impossible, then I will be forced to skip the short URL and use the style with the variable in it.)
3. Last, string special characters from the URL in the example like www.example.com/wiki/index.php?=title=Garden,_Store! ought to be this www.example.com/wiki/index.php?=title=Garden_Store .

Another example of that might be www.example.com/wiki/index.php?=title=Garden_Store,_Inc. ought to be www.example.com/wiki/index.php?=title=Garden_Store_Inc

One last example, us to make sure that I am communicating well, would be getting this "/title=Garden%20Store,%20Inc" but wanting this "/index.php?title=Garden%20Store%20Inc" as I know that the spaces are replaced with underscores inside of mediawiki.

Thanks so much for walking a newbie the last bit to the finish line on this one.

Cheers.

Jason

Comment: Note, it's not a problem for your case but on a public website this might split pagerank.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following rules should do what you need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ $1\_$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\._](.*)$ $1$2 [L]
```

First rule does replace space with underscore and the other line strips all chars you don't want to stay in the resulting URL. Note, your will probably need to add some more, if you want.

Comment: Kamil, thanks so much for the post. I tried it but it does not seem to be catching one use case. Please see this snippet of the tail end of an URL that is being passed through. This is from tailing the log named ssl_access_log. Would you have a suggestion to how to drop that comma that is in there?                                                                                                 &title=New%20Example%20Group,%20Limited HTTP/1.1" 200

Comment: @JasonSjobeck you can try to add the comma into square brackets of second rewrite rule - it'll then remove it from the result.

Comment: I attempted this but it does not seem to be catching them. I guess I really am new to this.  May I kindly ask for a new line from you please with what that would look like.    Second, I just learned one other thing & that is that I do not need to replace these with spaces, or replace spaces with the underscore character, I am allowed to have simple spaces in the URL, as it does handle correctly the %20 on its own. I dont know if that helps us or hurts us but I wanted to mention it. I think it helps us. I think that means we only need drop the "," and "1" and we're there. Thx

Comment: @JasonSjobeck not sure, if I understand correctly / you need to drop the above mentioned from the query string as well? If so, one more parameter to the rules should help - change `[L]` in both rules to `[L,QSA]` - now it'll process also the parameters. If you need to drop also "1" just remove it from the `[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\._]` / it'll be `[^a-zA-Z02-9\/\._]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts & time & we got close to getting it but we didn't get it. I actually now think that there is something else that I do not yet know about affecting rewrite. I have enabled rewrite.log and am tailing it while hitting the page and it isnt showing expected behavior. We have actually side-stepped this for now since we have run out of time. How do you advise I mark this thread? Thx again for assistance! Appreciated. Jason

Comment: @JasonSjobeck have no idea how to mark it / probably delete it as it's not solved and most likely will not help anyone else?